# pROC R package with customized cutoff values?

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

Can I use some pre-specified cutoff values (thresholds) to plot a ROC curve with the `pROC` package? For example, can I input control/case values and my own threshold points where to calculate corresponding sensitivities and specificities?

Comment: From the comments you left in my answer, it looks like what you are asking is NOT a ROC curve. A ROC curve goes over all thresholds. If you limit the thresholds, your curve is not a ROC any more. So please rephrase your question.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make any sense to me why the hell you'd like to do, probably beacuse your question is too specific. If you tell us a bit more about the reason behind your choice to do this, a better answer may appear.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `?plot.roc`.

Let's say you have:

```
my.cutoff <- 0.6
```

Then you can do:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
plot.roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, print.thres = my.cutoff)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I want something different than this. I do not know how pROC select thresholds to calculate sensitivities and specificities. However, I want to calculate them at threshold values specified myself. For example, roc(case=mycases, control=mycontrols, ...); in here is there a way to specify my own threshold values?

Comment: @Vish I used 0.6 but you can specify any cutoff you want in `my.cutoff`, you can also pass a vector of cutoffs.

Comment: @Vish is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: Thanks so much again for your attention. However, I want to use my own thresholds to generate the ROC curve. For example, roc(case=mycases, control=mycontrols, Thresholds = c(0.6, 1, 1.5, 1.8). Then the function produce ROC curve and AUC considering ONLY those specified thresholds. I guess this is not possible with pROC package. Is it? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Vish You cannot generate a ROC curve with only a few thresholds: it isn't ROC any more.

Answer (score 1):

## This is no longer a ROC curve

To address your comments in my other answer (but not answer your question, which can't be answered as I commented above), I can give you a way to do what you seem to want. Please do NOT under any circumstances refer to this as a ROC curve: it is not! Please come up with a descriptive name yourself, depending on the purpose of this exercise (which you never explained).

You can do what you seem to want indirectly with `pROC`: you compute the ROC on all thresholds, extract the coordinates you want: and use a trapezoid function to finish up.

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
my.cutoff <- c(0.6, 1, 1.5, 1.8)
roc.obj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
like.coordinates <- coords(roc.obj, c(-Inf, sort(my.cutoff), Inf), input="threshold", ret=c("specificity", "sensitivity"))
```

Now you can plot the results as:

```
plot(like.coordinates$specificity, like.coordinates$sensitivity, xlim=c(1, 0), type="l")
```

And compute the `AUC`, for instance with the `trapz` function in package `caTools`:

```
library(caTools)
trapz(like.coordinates$specificity, like.coordinates$sensitivity)
```

Once again, you did NOT plot a ROC curve and the AUC you computed is NOT that of a ROC curve.